# How to make padding clickable inside the datatables

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, datatables

I searched a lot and read different question about making padding clickable but I cann't find about `datatables` cell pading. I wanna to know how can i make this possible . I attached the screeshot in which the `green` portion i wanna to make clickable.

[image: Green Portion Of Paading 8px]

I would like to ask one more thing is `rowlink.js` plugin will work with database using datatables. If it is possible than give me a simple example to understand that. I tried but that all features of `rowlink.js` was not working with `datatables`. Thanks :)

```
    <?php

    $con = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '' )or die( 'can not connect to server' . $conn->connect_error );
    if ( $con ) {
        mysql_select_db( 'syspos', $con )or die( 'can not seletc the database' . $conn->connect_error );
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbproduct";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clickable Paddind</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<style>

    td a { 
   display: block;      
}




td {
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;


}


    tbody:hover tr:hover td  {
        background-color:   #A9A9A9;
    }   
    tbody:hover tr:hover a {
        color: white;

    }



    </style>
</head>

<body>
<br><br>

<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="data" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Name</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="my" data-link="row" class="rowlink">
        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
                  {
                    echo '

                    <tr>

                        <td id="one"  ><a href="#">'.$row["cat_id"].'</a></td>
                        <td id="two" ><a href="#">'.$row["product_name"].'</a></td>
                        <td id="three" ><a href="#">'.$row["quantity"].'</a></td>


                    </tr>'; 

                  }
                    ?>
        </tbody>            
        </table>

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#data').DataTable();
} );

</script>
```

Comment: In CSS, change `td{padding: xpx;}` to `td a{padding : xpx;}`

Comment: @Znaneswar its default datatble padding, how can i change ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Znaneswar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3840929/znaneswar) idea:

I've modified your example to create fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nrfsgs0x/2/

If you remove css, run the fiddle and open dev tools on `td` element, you find that `padding: 8px` goes from `bootstrap.css` as a style for selector `.table>tbody>tr>td`

To overwrite it, you need to provide more specific selector with `padding: 0`.
The trick is to add tag to class name so the selector looks as `table.table tbody tr td`.

Then you need to add `padding: 8px` to `a`.
Refer to the fiddle for details.

P.S. in fact, I'd suggest you to add a specific class to your table and use the class as namespace in css to avoid leaking your specific styles for the particular table to other places in your html page where you probably don't need them.
I did it first but then modified the fiddle to keep it as close to your code as I could.
You may refer to the first version of the fiddle to get what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/nrfsgs0x/0/